# django views letters for editing

Tags: django, django-views

I am writing a software where the client needs to send some letters in some standard format to its clients. The format sometimes changes a little bit for some clients. I need to give him the facility to edit the letter I am generating. He also wants to save some formats to be used later on.

Basically a letter may have different versions based on which client or some unquantifiable criterion he is sending those letters.

I have generated the letter through views but have no idea on how to give this functionality to him.

Any leads would be appreciated.....

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question in the right way, this would be my approach:

Create a model to store formats and create a relationship between those formats and the clients ( create a model for the clients if not exists ). We don't know anything about your formats, but I suppose they can be different letter templates.

Then, present a form to the user for choosing a format based on a client selection ( clients and formats should be related ) and when the user chooses the client show the view with the correct format ( letter template ? ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes you have understood the question right. But he wants things to be done at his end. As letter formats change over time. And he wants to change them without admin interference. The letters use variables from different models. Position of variables may change over time also.